# How to solve this simple problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So my younger brother asked me to solve a simple problem, but I'm not sure how to solve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

$$a^3 - 1/ a^3 = 4. $$

Prove that  $$a - 1/a = 1$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using  $$\displaystyle \left(a-\frac{1}{a}\right)^3=\left(a^3-\frac{1}{a^3}\right)-3\cdot a\cdot \frac{1}{a}\left(a-\frac{1}{a}\right)$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \left(a-\frac{1}{a}\right)^3=4-3\displaystyle \left(a-\frac{1}{a}\right)\;,$$ Now Put $\displaystyle \left(a-\frac{1}{a}\right)=x$

So we get $$\displaystyle x^3=4-3x\Rightarrow x^3+3x-4=0\Rightarrow (x-1)\cdot (x^2+x+4)=0$$

So we get $x=1$ or $\displaystyle x^2+x+4 =0\Rightarrow x=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1-16}}{2}$ (No real values of $x$)

Comment: Not possible? You mean in the reals?

Comment: Yes means for real values of $x$

Answer (score 0):

By reverse approach solve quadratic equation

$$ x - \frac{1}{x} =4 \rightarrow  x_{1,2} = 2 \pm \sqrt 5 $$

checks ok because

$$ \frac {1}{x_1} = \frac{1}{ 2 + \sqrt 5} = - 2 + \sqrt 5 $$

and plugging into cubic relation, I get after simplifying,

$$ x_1^3 -\frac{1}{x_1^3}= 76 ,\,  x_2^3 -\frac{1}{x_2^3}= 76 \,  !! $$

Answer (score -2):

So let's solve the first problem for $a$ in the reals.
$a^3-a^{-3}=4$. If thrown into mathematica you get the real solutions are $\frac{1}{2}(1\pm \sqrt{5})$. Then solving the second for $a$ in the reals gives us $a-a^{-1}=1$. This also has the same solutions. Alternatively if we were to assume $a>0$ both simplify to $a^2=a+1$.

Comment: I didn't down vote but I suspect the negative reaction is because the answer doesn't really shed light on the problem for future readers. Mathematica is useful but to improve your answer you need to explain what you have done and how it relates to the problem at hand.